# ExtJs HTML/DOM code optimization

Tags: html, extjs4.2

Spent already a lot of resources to figure out how to optimize extJs HTML code.
I have simple combobox with a label and extjs throw on a page this:

```
<tr role="presentation" id="inputs[1].TypeId-inputRow" class="x-form-item-input-row">
    <td role="presentation" id="inputs[1].TypeId-labelCell" style="" valign="top" halign="left" width="88" class="x-field-label-cell">
        <label 
        id="inputs[1].TypeId-labelEl" 
        for="inputs[1].TypeId-inputEl" 
        class="x-form-item-label x-unselectable x-form-item-label-left" 
        style="width:83px;margin-right:5px;" unselectable="on">

        Placement ID:
    </label>
    </td>
    <td role="presentation" class="x-form-item-body x-form-trigger-wrap-focus" id="inputs[1].TypeId-bodyEl" colspan="2">
    <table id="inputs[1].TypeId-triggerWrap" class="x-form-trigger-wrap" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: auto;">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="inputs[1].TypeId-inputCell" class="x-form-trigger-input-cell">
                    <div class="x-hide-display x-form-data-hidden" role="presentation" id="ext-gen1311">
            </div>
            <input 
                id="inputs[1].TypeId-inputEl" 
                type="text" 
                class="x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text x-trigger-noedit x-form-focus x-field-form-focus x-field-default-form-focus" 
                autocomplete="off" 
                            name="inputs[1].TypeId" 
                placeholder="DATA SOURCE" 
                readonly="readonly" 
                aria-invalid="false" 
                data-errorqtip="" 
                style="width: 137px;">
            </td>
                    <td valign="top" class=" x-trigger-cell x-unselectable" style="width:22px;" id="ext-gen1310">
            <div class="x-trigger-index-0 x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger x-form-trigger-first" role="button" id="ext-gen1309">
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How could I change tables inside a tables just for simple xtype: 'combobox'?
I have hundreds like that on a page, it slows down a lot because very heavy HTML code.

it could be done with simple div wit ha float on it, why does extJS renders all this table code?

Comment: Ext is beautiful in that that it abstracts from the HTML. So why would you need to change the underlying HTML, when you do not need to think in HTML terms in Ext?

Comment: because I do not want that much HTML on my page when it could be done in a few divs

Answer (score 0):

If you want/need a simpler markup in Ext, the only way is to code your own component where you can define a simpler one.

There is no way of simplifying the Ext generated markup without a danger of breaking functionality or layout engine.